# I am looking for a service management software like Linux systemctl for Windows

Tags: windows, services

I am looking for windows free software with the following requirements
Ideally, I am looking for functionality equivalent to Linux's systemctl.

The standard Windows services could not meet my needs.

- The ability to register arbitrary commands, such as exe and py files.
- It should be able to run the cli program in the background.
- The standard output and standard error output is output to a text file with a timestamp so that it can be checked later.
- When a cli program terminates abnormally, it is automatically restarted.
- The CMD window is not displayed when the cli program is executed.
- The registered programs can be listed. The number of times a program has been restarted after an abnormal termination should also be displayed.
- No need to make any changes to the cli program.
- Free of charge and with no limitation of functions.

I am looking for a free software.

The Windows built-in service does not have the ability to save standard output to a text file.
Also, the program to be registered must be an `.exe`, and service-specific logic must be added to the `.exe`.

I was going to use WSL2 systemctl, but WSL2 stops systemctl after a minute or so when I close the terminal.

Comment: Did you check NSSM? I don't know how well it covers all  your requirements, but it's the most popular free option for sure and I don't think you'll find anything better.

Answer (score 0):

You could try NSSM. It's free and open-source.

- You can use it to register any executable (such as .exe or .py files)
  as a Windows service
- It allows you to run CLI programs in the background as Windows
  services.
- It redirects both standard output and standard error output to files and you can specify the filenames with timestamps
- It's possible to configure automatic restart on failure
- It can run programs without displaying the command prompt window
- It provides commands to list all registered services and their
  properties, including restart counts after abnormal termination.
- If you want to avoid making any changes to the CLI program itself,
  you can do it by wrapping the CLI program with a script or a batch
  file.

Create a wrapper.bat file like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set LOG_DIR=C:\Path\To\Logs

mkdir "%LOG_DIR%" 2>nul

:run_program
"%~dp0\YourCLIProgram.exe" >> "%LOG_DIR%\output.log" 2>> "%LOG_DIR%\error.log"
echo Program terminated abnormally. Restarting...
goto run_program
```

Then in NSSM:

```
nssm install MyService "C:\Path\To\wrapper.bat"
nssm set MyService AppDirectory "C:\Path\To\Directory\Containing\Batch\File"
nssm start MyService
```